# How to sort a dictionary based on values with tuple

Tags: python, python-3.x, sorting, dictionary

Here I have dictionary like

```
d_ = {"k3":(2,3), "k1":(4,5), "k5":(8,9), "k2":(6,8), "k4":(2,7)}
```

I have to sort this based on descending order of first value in the tuples.
I am doing this:

```
 sorted(d_.items(), key=d_.get(1) , reverse=True)
```

But I am getting this:

```
[('k5', (8, 9)), ('k4', (2, 7)), ('k3', (2, 3)), ('k2', (6, 8)), ('k1', (4, 5))]
```

The Output should look like this:

```
[("k5",(8,9)),("k2",(6,8)),("k1",(4,5)),("k3",(2,3)),("k4",(2,7))]
```

Comment: Please consider adding a code sample, or revising the one you posted in this question. As it currently stands, its formatting and scope make it hard for us to help you; here is a [great resource](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to get you started on that. Good luck with your code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
>>> [(k, d_.get(k)) for k in sorted(d_, key=d_.get, reverse=True)]
[('k5', (8, 9)), ('k2', (6, 8)), ('k1', (4, 5)), ('k4', (2, 7)), ('k3', (2, 3))]
```

**NOTE**: The last two elements for this answer are swapped from the example answer the OP gave.

Answer (score 1):

Something as simple as this could also work:

```
>>> d_ = {"k3":(2,3), "k1":(4,5), "k5":(8,9), "k2":(6,8), "k4":(2,7)}
>>> sorted(d_.items(), key = lambda x : -x[1][0])
[('k5', (8, 9)), ('k2', (6, 8)), ('k1', (4, 5)), ('k3', (2, 3)), ('k4', (2, 7))]
```